# Prevent spaces in stringized output

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a C preprocessor macro

```
#define QUOTE(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

If I use it to stringize JSON like this:

```
QUOTE(
{
    "a":1,
    "b":2
}
)
```

The output is

```
"{ \"a\":1, \"b\":2 }"
```

Is there any way to remove the spaces? I.e.

```
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
```

If not, the wider problem is I'm writing test cases for JSON parsing, and I want to make the JSON readable in test cases but condense without whitespace. After testing parsing I test generating JSON output from the parsed result, and want to compare against the original string, but the generated JSON contains no spaces. Perhaps there are other solutions than using a macro...

Comment: I believe it is implementation defined... Such as `#define PLUS(a,b) a+b` might expand into `a + b` or `a+b` on different compilers...

Comment: Don't you want to be able to differentiate between `QUOTE(12)` (single argument of `12`) and `QUOTE(1 2)` (2 arguments of `1` and `2`)?

Comment: @e.dan see the wider problem at the bottom, this is just a simplified example. Perhaps I should use letters instead...

Comment: I don't know how to do this with the ellipsis. But for single macro arguments you use the `##` to concatenate the arguments like in `#define QUOTE(a,b) printf(a##b)`. You can try (in C) `QUOTE("xx", "yy")` with or without a newline. You'll get rid off the space.

Comment: @harper — the result of `##` should be an identifier; it isn’t a general space eliminator.

Comment: If you don’t want spaces in the output, don’t put spaces in the input, or use a different tool to convert the data from readable to JSON.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `##` should result in a valid preprocessing token. It does not need to be an identifier.

Comment: The spaces are well-defined and standardized, it's the nature of the # operator: `Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens
becomes a single space character in the character string literal. White space before the
first preprocessing token and after the last preprocessing token composing the argument
is deleted.`

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe I'll strip all spaces from the string instead then as I don't have any spaces in JSON values.

Comment: Why can't you just write string literals directly, with escape sequences? `"\"a\":1,"` new line `"\"b\":2`. This gets pre-processed like you want it.

Comment: Maybe you should describe the problem you are trying to solve. Are you creating C source with this approach? How do you get the JSON data into your macro calls? I assume you don't type it but somehow generate it. It might be easier to modify the generator or post-process its output.

Comment: @lundin Technically I could do that, but it's better to be able to paste/edit real JSON in the unit test without having to quote and escape every line.

Comment: @Bodo I did explain why I'm doing this in the question, it's JSON to use as input to a parser in unit tests. So I want to keep the JSON in the C++ unit test readable and easily editable while condensing to minified JSON for parsing and comparison with the recompiled result.

Answer (score 1):

As my JSON values don't contain spaces, my best solution so far is to remove spaces after creating the string:

```
#define QUOTE(...) #__VA_ARGS__

size_t stripSpaces(char *orig, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(orig[i] != ' ') { continue; }
        memmove(&orig[i], &orig[i+1], length - i - 2);
        i--;
        length--;
    }
    return length;
}

void unitTest() {
    char json[] = QUOTE(
        {
            "messageType":176,
            "channel":1,
            "controller":67,
            "ccValue":127
        }
    );

    size_t jsonLength = stripSpaces(json, sizeof(json));
}
```

Edit: Thanks to the suggestion by @Bodo, instead of stripping spaces I can also just ignore spaces when comparing the strings.

```
bool compareJSON(const char * string1, size_t string1Size, const char * string2, size_t string2Size) {
    bool inQuotes = false;
    for (size_t string1Pos = 0, string2Pos = 0; string1Pos < string1Size && string2Pos < string2Size; ++string1Pos, ++string2Pos) {
        if(!inQuotes) {
            // skip spaces
            while(string1[string1Pos] == ' ' && string1Pos < string1Size) { string1Pos++; }
            while(string2[string2Pos] == ' ' && string2Pos < string2Size) { string2Pos++; }
            // check if we have reached the end of either
            if(string1Pos == string1Size || string2Pos == string2Size) {
                // if both at the end, equal strings, otherwise not equal
                return string1Pos == string1Size && string2Pos == string2Size;
            }
        }
        // compare character
        if(string1[string1Pos] != string2[string2Pos]) {
            return false;
        }
        if(string1[string1Pos] == '\"') {
            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to implement your own comparison function that ignores whitespace in the strings.